# Enterprise Architect call operation of provided interface

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I have Enterpise Architect 12

In a component diagram I have a component with a provided interface and another component with a required interface,the interface provided is related to an interface object

[image]

With which relationship I can indicate which operation is invoked in the server interface?, for example "getOperationA"

Answer (score 2):

With no relationship. You draw a sequence diagram to show operation invocations

[image]

or you show it as CallOperation in an activity diagram.

[image]

Comment: You could use a communication diagram instead, whilst (officially) you should use component instances for this EA will let you get away with placing communications messages between components if the diagram type is a communication diagram. That way you could keep the component representation.

Comment: @muszeo Yes and no. The OP asks for relations to show operation calls. Like many people he does not realize that calls are not shown in static diagrams but with dynamic ones. You can place the OP's diagram additionally in any dynamic diagram, but you will not use a static diagram for purely showing dynamic behavior.